# How to select table in mysql with comparison by 2 rows using value from array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select

I have a select query like this one:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` 
WHERE `is_deleted`!='1'  AND 
(
 (`a`='1' AND `b`='1') 
  OR 
 (`a`='2' AND `b`='2')
) 
ORDER by `timestamp` DESC LIMIT 0,20
```

How to make a select query using "IN" operator with comparison rows `a` and `b`?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM \`table\` 
WHERE \`is_deleted\`!='1'  AND 
\`a\` IN ('1', '2') AND \`a\`=\`b\`
ORDER by \`timestamp\` DESC LIMIT 0,20`

Comment: Thanks you!
That solved my problem.
I missed such a simple thing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also you could use `in` with several fields at once.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` 
WHERE `is_deleted`!='1' 
    AND (`a`, `b`) IN ((1,1),(2,2))
ORDER by `timestamp` DESC LIMIT 0,20
```

It's strange, but there is no description of this behavior in the documentation [IN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in), only a little note in the comments.

> The IN operator also works with tuples, at least in version 4.1:
>   mysql> select (3,4) in ((2,3),(3,4));